# Rich Text - MS Access to Windows Forms rich text box

Tags: ms-access, richtextbox, rtf

I have an MS Access database that has been upgraded over the years to 2016.  I’ve been tasked with converting the data & system into a Sql Server database & Windows forms (C#).  Most of the original text in MS Access is rich text.  I have been able to read the data out of access & store it in Sql Server no problem.  But when I read it out of Sql Server and try to load it into a RichTextBox it generates a “File format is not valid” error.  The line of code that is problematic is:

```
rtb.Rtf = dr["req_sum_desc"].ToString().Trim();
```

Of course if I use the .Text property it sees the mark up tags as part of the string. When I look at what was originally stored as rich text in MS Access it looks more like HTML.  Here is the beginning of a sample:

```
<div><font face=Arial size=2>Request for 68 FTEs, 25 faculty and 43 staff, 
E&amp;G funded</font></div><div>&nbsp;</div><div><font face=Arial 
size=2>Instruction &nbsp;</font></div><div><font face=Arial size=2>Faculty 
hiring has increased to address enrollment growth to meet student demand 
for courses to shorten time to graduate. &nbsp .....
```

I've tried using a webbrowser control & the clipboard to convert it to a richtext string ...

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
web.DocumentText = dr["req_sum_desc"].ToString().Trim();
web.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
web.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
rtb.Paste();
```

But that just gave me the field in the DocumentText rather than the contents of the field (really weird).
I've been looking for a windows control that can handle both HTML & RTF.

Does anyone have any ideas or solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure a rich text box control supports this form of HTML, but writing an [encapsulating RTF encoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee204432(v=exchg.80).aspx) is a pretty easy task. It's a horrible form of RTF though, since it's really an HTML document. Some Office programs, such as Outlook, heavily use it.

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct, a rich text box does not support this type of string.  But thanks for the reference, I'll give that a whirl.